# Not able to perform the delete operation from one table to another table using multiple one-to-one relationship?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

1. First, I've created a DbContext class which contains the relationships between the tables

```cs
           modelBuilder.Entity<Projects>()
             .HasOne(p => p.ProjectDeliveryContact)
             .WithOne(i => i.Delivery)
             .HasForeignKey<ProjectContacts>(b => b.del)
             .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


           modelBuilder.Entity<Projects>()
             .HasOne(p => p.ProjectInvoiceContact)
             .WithOne(i => i.Invoice)
             .HasForeignKey<ProjectContacts>(b => b.inv)
             .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


           modelBuilder.Entity<Projects>()
             .HasOne(p => p.ProjectCommercialContact)
             .WithOne(i => i.Commercial)
             .HasForeignKey<ProjectContacts>(b => b.Com)
             .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


           modelBuilder.Entity<Projects>()
             .HasOne(p => p.ProjectEscalationContact)
             .WithOne(i => i.Escalation)
             .HasForeignKey<ProjectContacts>(b => b.esc)
             .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

2. I've created the entity 'Projects' like this -

```cs
 public class Projects
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }   
        public List<ProjectRisks> ProjectRisk { get; set; } //This object can be used to get/set 
                                                            //project risk for a particular project
        public List<StatementOfWork> statementOfWorks { get; set; } //This object can be used to get/set 
                                                                    //statement of work for a particular project
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ScopeSummary { get; set; }        
        public bool IsVerified { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }     
        public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
        public virtual Customers Customer { get; set; } //This object can be used to get/set 
                                                        //customer for a particular project
        public int? OptimusDeliveryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OptimusDeliveryId")]
        public virtual OptimusContact OptimusDeliveryContact { get; set; } //This object can be used to get/set 
                                                                           //optimus contact of delivery type for a particular project
        public int? OptimusSalesId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OptimusSalesId")]
        public virtual OptimusContact OptimusSalesContact { get; set; } //This object can be used to get/set 
                                                                        //optimus contact of sales type for a particular project
        public int? DeliveryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DeliveryId")]
        public virtual ProjectContacts ProjectDeliveryContact { get; set; } //This object can be used to get/set 
                                                                     //project contact of delivery type for a particular project
        public int? CommercialId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CommercialId")]
        public virtual ProjectContacts ProjectCommercialContact { get; set; } //This object can be used to get/set 
                                                                       //project contact of commercial type for a particular project
        public int? InvoiceId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("InvoiceId")]
        public virtual ProjectContacts ProjectInvoiceContact { get; set; } //This object can be used to get/set 
                                                                    //project contact of invoice type for a particular project
        public int? EscalationId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("EscalationId")]
        public virtual ProjectContacts ProjectEscalationContact { get; set; } //This object can be used to get/set 
                                                                       //project contact of escalation type for a particular project
        public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
        public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
        public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UpdatedBy")]
        public virtual User UpdatedByUser { get; set; }
    }
```

3. I've created the entity 'Project Contacts' like this -

```cs
    public class ProjectContacts
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ContactTypeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ContactTypeId")]
        public virtual ContactType ContactType { get; set; } //This object can be used to get/set 
                                                             //project contact for a particular contact type
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

4. Now, I want my 'Project contacts' to be deleted everytime I delete an object from 'Projects' class.
5. But, everytime my projects gets deleted but project contacts stays as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the code that you are using to delete? Usually to remove the entity and is relations with other entities you have to include them before the remove operation. For example:

```
var project = context.Projects.Include(b => b.ProjectInvoiceContact).First();
context.Remove(project);
```

Another thing that may help you is, you have more than one "ProjectContacts" so i think that the relation should be one to many.